# Continue for loop after exception java

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

This is my code:

```
if (Recipients_To != null) {
    for (int i = 0; i < Recipients_To.length; i++) {
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, Recipients_To[i].toString());
        Transport.send(message);
    }
}
```

I have more than 500 Recipients list to send mail and this **code will send personal mail to each recipients**. But if i got exception in between this for loop **i want to continue loop** for remaining recipients. How can i do?

Comment: Answer aside, your variable name `Recipients_To` does not follow Java code conventions

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to use  `try` `catch` blocks to do this, like so

```
for (int i = 0; i < Recipients_To.length; i++) 
{
    try {
       message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,Recipients_To[i].toString());
       Transport.send(message);
    }
    catch (YourException e){
       //Do some thing to handle the exception
    }
}
```

This catches the potential issue and will still continue with the for loop once the exception has been handled.

Answer (score 5):

You can catch the exception e.g.

```
try {
    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, Recipients_To[i].toString());
    Transport.send(message);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // handle it or leave it be
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Technically, it's simply a matter of catching the exception (see Murat K's answer). I would recommend, however, that since you're sending e-mail, that you do cease sending the rest when the first exception occurs, unless you are certain that it is an error you can safely ignore. A few examples of things that can go wrong:

- Invalid credentials: this means that if you continue attempting to send, every subsequent attempt will also fail. Best case: no e-mail sent. Worst case: SMTP server blocks your access due to excessive login failures.
- Malformed recipient address: no issue to continue trying the other addresses, but you need to do something with this error (remove recipient from list for future mailings)
- Misconfigured mail server address: each iteration of your loop will try to connect to the mailserver, and fail. This will slow down the method tremendously (server timeouts) or spam your log (assuming you did something with the exception)

So please consider your course of action carefully when handling e-mail.

Comment: Surely you can add this in the catch block though? We can have our checks to see if things are working correctly there, and if not break from the for loop

Comment: Of course, I'm merely trying to say that blindly continuing execution on any exception is probably not the best idea

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
if (Recipients_To != null) {
    for (int i = 0; i < Recipients_To.length; i++) {
        try {
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, Recipients_To[i].toString());
            Transport.send(message);
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            //Log your exception here or do whatever you want to happen in case of exception
        }
    }
}
```